# How to make StyleCop allow "_" discard in LINQ query syntax?

Tags: stylecop

StyleCop returns the warning

> Variable '_' should begin with lower-case letter

when the '_' is used as a discard in a LINQ query-syntax block:

[image: disallowed _ variable]

Is there any way to globally configure StyleCop in a Visual Studio project/solution to allow underscores to be used like this, without a warning, please?

Using StyleCop.Analysers 1.1.118